# Facebook Like button cyclically opens and closes a popup window, facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I associated a Facebook account with my GaiaOnline account; we use Connect to accomplish this. I created a JS Like button for a page at FB's dedicated page:  **developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like**

The Like button's code was

Upon clicking the Like button in XP/firefox 3.6.13, while logged into Gaia and FB, a popup window rapidly opens and closes cyclically until the process is terminated. This behavior is not repeatable on other windows machines, macs or chrome. Presumably this is Facebook trying to initiate a FB login page, per their third-party login process: **developers.facebook.com/blog/post/312**

My history identifies this page as "http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest135.open.dev.gaiaonline.com%2Fforum%2Fentertainment-discussion%2Fthe-roommate-what-s-the-best-thing-about-having-a-roommate%2Ft.67947263%2F".

A video of this transpiring is uploaded to Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1asJ4kMNL6w

What is causing the popup behavior, and what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling 3rd party cookies
http://support.mozilla.com/kk/questions/761194#answer-127335